# Wake on Lan over internet not working

Tags: networking, wake-on-lan

I'm pretty new to networking so sorry if the problem is obvious :D. So basically I'm trying to do WOL and I got to the point where I'm able to start my computer on LAN, but I want to be able to do it over the internet.

I forwarded port 7 UDP(I tried 9 too without success), configured a static IP for my computer on my router, entered my computer's MAC address and public IP in the WOL app I'm using on my phone, but my computer doesn't want to start. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, your router must remember your sleeping target machine's MAC address. IP address to MAC address mappings are kept in a dynamic "ARP table", and ARP mappings (ARP table entries) usually time out after around 2 minutes of inactivity. So it requires that you set a static ARP mapping for that machine's IP -> MAC address. This is usually separate from setting up a static DHCP reservation for that machine. If your router doesn't have a way  to set static ARP mappings, and the sleeping target device doesn't have a fancy NIC that responds to ARPs while the host sleeps, you may just be out of luck, unless you can put open source firmware on your router.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I figured out that it can't be done becuase my router doesn't support port forwarding to the broadcast address. Plus it doesn't support custom ARP mapping as you said either.